# Django: Make POST Requests on Server Side with CSRF Token

Tags: python, django

My website uses Django's default auth module to do user authentications. Usually, user just needs to fill out a html form in the login page with his/her username and password and click submit, then the CSRF-protected data will be posted to `/auth/login/`, the Django auth endpoint.

But now for some reason I also need to do this on my server. This is the same server as the backend authentication server. After researching and trials and errors, I finally got:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
import requests

class fb_login(View):
    "login view for Facebook OAuth"

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def get(self, request):
        ''' code that gets username and password info. from user's FB profile
        is not shown here '''

        # login code
        url = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/login/'
        client = requests.session()
        # Retrieve the CSRF token first
        client.get(url)  # sets cookie
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
        form = {'username': uname, 'password': pw}
        header = {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
        resp = requests.post(url, data=form, headers=header)
```

I also tried to add csrf token as part of the form field:

```
form = {'username': uname, 'password': pw , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}
resp = requests.post(url, data=form)
```

I pretty much just followed the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/). But I still get the 403 error saying `CSRF verification failed, CSRF cookie not set`. I wonder if I missed something here? I've double-checked the process against the Django doc but I cannot find anything that might be wrong or missing.

Comment: Does your page template contain `{% csrf_token %}` inside the form tag?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes. There's no problem logging in on the client side, which is typical form post action with {% csrf_token %}. But now I need to achieve this on the server side.

Comment: I've just looked into the data sent from one of my forms, and it sends the form data `csrfmiddlewaretoken=xxx` and the cookie `csrftoken=xxx`. Maybe you need to set the cookie instead/in addition of the form field.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for your help! Do you know how to set the cookie in the server code? Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird: Well, I use the CSRFMiddleware, and the `render()` function for my views and I have it automatically. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) for alternatives.

Comment: @rodrigo I'll take  a look, thanks. Can your server-side requests pass CSRF protection?

Comment: @JFreebird: Oh, sorry, I don't use server-side requests, I'm just guessing. You can try `requests.post(..., cookies={'csrftoken':csrftoken})` or something like that.

Comment: @rodrigo That worked for me, cookies are indeed needed here in order to pass the CSRF certification. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @rodrigo, cookies are also needed to pass the CSRF security check. Here's a simple code snippet:

```
csrftoken = requests.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']
form = {'username': uname, 'password': pw}
header = {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
cookies = {'csrftoken': csrftoken}
resp = requests.post(url, data=form, headers=header, cookies=cookies)
```